# Is a topological sorting of a poset a total ordering?

Tags: graph-theory, relations, order-theory

I have been taught by my professor that the topological sort gives a total ordering of a partial order. However, I do not see how this is the case. You are simply rearranging the elements in the partial order set in the topological sort, so how does that convert a poset to a total order?

This link supports what my professor says. [link](http://At%20its%20core,%20a%20topological%20sort,%20or%20a%20linear%20extension,%20is%20a%20total%20ordering%20of%20a%20partially%20ordered%20set.)

> At its core, a topological sort, or a linear extension, is a total ordering of a partially ordered set.

Comment: Your arrange the elements of the poset into an ordered set.  That is, the arrangement defines a total order, which is a new relation on the given set.  Topological sorting produces total orders that are *compatible* with the given partial order.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi what exactly do you mean by compatible

Comment: If $a\leq b$ in the partial order, then $a \leq b$ in the total order.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Thank you. I am not sure why this is not clearer on the internet or in textbooks. If you would like, paste your answer and I will accept.

Comment: The term "topological sort" for a linear extension, is an absurdity.